# How can i debug this SQL error..?

Tags: mysql

> You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to
>   your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near 'Krul. Good
>   bye!.')' at line 1

I have a LONG script with a lot of loops. It seems to work and then I get thsi error, what does it mean?

Update:
Oh okay, I see what's wrong. I am storing a variable that sometimes have an apostrophe in it, so it messes up my SQL syntax.
e.g.
$name = "You and D'dog are cool."
my sql syntax would be like this '$name'

How can I fix this?

**Update 2:**
I am using addslashes()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means you have a syntax error there, most likely an unescaped string with a apostrophe. It's not possible to help better without seeing the script.

EDIT: Don't use `addslashes()`, use a function that is designed for escaping SQL queries. In your cases that would be [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php).

Comment: Thanks for the help! When looking at the example, I have trouble understanding this, specifically the sprintf and the percent s: 
$query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user='%s' AND password='%s'",
            mysql_real_escape_string($user),
            mysql_real_escape_string($password));
What is $s